# Index was outside the bounds of the array while assigning label to array

Tags: c#

```
string[] SalesReferenceArray = {};
int i=0;
if (chk_Select.Checked == true)
{
    SalesReferenceArray[i] = Convert.ToString((Label)grdSales.FindControl("lblSalesReference"));
     i++;
}
```

Index was outside the bounds of the array while assigning label to array

Answer (score 3):

```
string[] SalesReferenceArray = {};
```

Your array is empty, i.e. it does not have any items. Trying to access first item (i.e. item at index 0) gives you IndexOutOfRange error, because index of item should be non-negative and less than array length.

If you need to have only one item, then you don't need array at all. Just declare variable of string type:

```
string SalesReference;
```

If you want to add/remove items dynamically then use list instead of array:

```
List<string> SalesReferences = new List<string>();
if (chk_Select.Checked) // don't compare with true
{
    string reference = Convert.ToString((Label)grdSales.FindControl("lblSalesReference"));
    SalesReferences.Add(reference);
}
```

NOTE: I think you need to use Label.Text instead of trying to convert label to string.

Comment: how can i declare dynamic array

Comment: @KrishnaPrabha use list, as I mentioned above

Answer (score 1):

You are creating an empty array with 0 size, i.e. you are using the short-hand assignment syntax and not specifying any elements.

You will need to fix your code by changing it to specify a size, like so:

```
string[] SalesReferenceArray = new string[10]; // creates an array with 10 empty elements
```

If you don't know the size of your array in advance, you might want to use a [List](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/6sh2ey19.aspx) instead:

```
List<string> salesReferenceList = new List<string>();

if (chk_Select.Checked == true)
{
    salesReferenceList.Add(Convert.ToString((Label)grdSales.FindControl("lblSalesReference")));
}
```

Answer (score 0):

A list would be more appropriate for you as it's dynamic.

```
List<string> SalesReferences = new List<string>();
```

then add to it like...

```
SalesReferences.Add("Hello World");
```